# Intentionally causing inconsistent printing between proccesses after fork()

Tags: c, printf, fork

I am currently doing an operation systems course and out study material claims the follow code:

```
int main() {
   fork();
   printf("hello");
   return 0;
}
```

can print any combination like "hellohello", "hhellollo", "hheelllloo" and similar.
I have tried and failed to reproduce this behavior myself, as the output is always "hellohello".
Is this behavior actually possible or is the material wrong?
If it is, is there any reliable way to reproduce it?

I have tried both adding `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` before the fork to disable the buffer and also tried doing the same on the ancient version of Linux we are using in class, redhat 7.3(the one from 2002), thinking maybe it was a problem that was fixed since.
I have also tried setting the std flag to c99 since it is a requirement for our assignments.

I am aware that the following code:

```
int main() {
   fork();
   printf("hel");
   printf("lo");
   return 0;
}
```

Can end up as "helhellolo" or "hellohello" but I am referring specifically to the case where the line is printed with a single printf call.

I am running Manjaro on linux 6.2.7 with gcc 12.1.1 and the redhat VM is running linux 2.4.18 with gcc 3.2 in case it matters.

Comment: It's highly, highly system-dependent.  I think I've seen the character-by-character interleaving your textbook suggests, but it was a long, long time ago.

Comment: Turning off buffering is a good idea.  I might also suggest replacing `printf` with a call to `void myputs(char *str) {while(*str) putchar(*str++); }`.  And if that doesn't work, try changing it to `void myputs(char *str) {while(*str) { putchar(*str++); usleep(1000); } }`

Comment: *I referring specifically to the case where the line is printed with a single printf call* The question is, when it's printing the string `"hello"`, does `printf` make one call to `write()`, or five?  If it makes five calls, then obviously interleaving is possible.  But I can imagine `printf` implementations that call `write` just once in this case, *even if output is unbuffered*.  When `printf` has a several characters in a row to print like that, it doesn't even need an output buffer in order to be able to call `write(,, 5)`.

Comment: That "ancient version of Linux" from 2002 probably isn't *nearly* old enough. :-)  Somewhere out there on the net there's a PDP-11 emulator running [V7 Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix).  That'd be worth a try, too.

Comment: @Steve Summit Not enough. Small writes are atomic, I believe. You'd have to write something ..larger than 4k?

Comment: These days, it is probably essentially impossible to get the arbitrary interleaving referred to by your course materials.  It would  almost certainly require an implementation of the standard I/O library that prints the buffer using single-character output operations (the analogue of `fputc()`), which is very unlikely.  It would also require scheduling flukes.  Any modern machine (say, newer than 1990) is unlikely to have code that mishandles that.  Even with older code, it's pretty unlikely that you'd see that behaviour, though there's nothing in the standards that says "it can't happen!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it can doesn't mean that it will. It just means that it's possible.

In my environment, stdio uses a 4 KiB buffer. This means that stdio accumulates output until it has 4 KiB of it rather than printing it immediately. Output is sent out in 4 KiB chunks. (stdout is a bit special in that it also flushes on a line feed and possibly other conditions.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
   for ( size_t i=0; i<20000; ++i ) {
      printf( "a" );
   }
}
```

```
$ strace ./b 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep ^write
write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 3616) = 3616
```

So if we prime the buffer so that it's almost full, we can get `helhellolo` from your code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void ) {
   for ( size_t i=0; i<4096-3; ++i ) {
      printf( "a" );
   }

   fork();
   printf("hello");
}
```

Output (sometimes):

```
...aaaahelaaaa...aaaahellolo
```

So in a program that writes more than just `hello`, it is entirely possible for the output of `printf("hello");` to be truncated.

Comment: Using this code I can reproduce this behavior! in fact, i have managed to recreate it with the simpler version: char buf[5];
 setvbuf(stdout, buf,0,5);
 printf("a");
 fork();
 printf("hello world");
 exit(0);
curiously, it does not work without the printf("a"), and this printf("a") can be either before and after the fork.
additionally, I am also wondering why I cannot reproduce it by disabling the buffer.
regardless, it appears to be possible to truncate the output like I asked.

Comment: Yeah, you can shorten the buf, but I wanted to demonstrate that it can happen in an program that does nothing special.

Comment: @Catto Buffering means that if you call `putchar('a'); putchar('b'); putchar('c'); fflush(stdout);`, the three putchar's write to an intermediate buffer which can then be written all at once with a single call to [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write), unless you've turned off buffering, in which case you get three different calls to `write()`.  Now, the question is, inside `printf`, as it's printing things, does it *always* use `putchar` to print everything (meaning that `putchar` copies things to the buffer, which later get written all at once)?

Comment: @ikegami Yeah thats fair,do you have any idea about that odd "a" requirement? I am guessing if the buffer is empty it will choose to print the given line regardless of buffer size, causing the whole line to be printed together, even if it wouldnt normally fit in the buffer.

Comment: If buffering is disabled, and if `printf` is simplemindedly written to always call `putchar`, then turning off buffering would work to show interleaving in your demo.  But a more-optimized implementation of `printf` might notice that, if there's no buffer, it might as well call `write` itself, on several characters at once, rather than bothering with `putchar` -- and in that case, you'd never see interleaving.

Comment: Re "*do you have any idea about that odd "a" requirement?*", hmm? My answer already explains that. Nothing is actually printed until the buffer is full, and then only the buffer is printed. So the problem happens when `hello` splits a buffer boundary.

Comment: @ikegami the thing is, "hello world" already splits the boundary even with an empty buffer, so as Steve summit explained, it is probably due to an optimized printf that skips the buffer, I'll try to find the current implementation to make sure.